# Pivot SQL specific Column

Tags: sql, pivot

Im stuck with the following

I want to use the values from the hours column as actual colums

Any idea how to do this?

```
Name|Team|Area|Count|Hour
Bob |J1  |UK  |1    | 8
Jim |J1  |UK  |1    | 9
Tim |J1  |UK  |1    | 9
Tom |J1  |UK  |1    | 10
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'as actual columns'? the task is not understandable. Please, post expected output for your data.

Comment: Use pivot function

Comment: You should tag the database system in use like MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL or SQLite for better answers.. Also post a expected output ascii data table

Answer (score 1):

Change this query based on your expected rows.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
 ( SELECT Name,Team,Area,Count,Hour FROM Tb_Name
 )
 PIVOT
     (COUNT(Name) FOR Hour IN ([8],[9],[10])) P
```